# For what value of $a$, $f(x)-\tan^{-1} (x^2+x+a)$ is surjective from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\left( 0, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$

Tags: functional-analysis

$\tan y=(x^2+x+a)$ where $\tan y$ is positive in $\left(0, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)$ so the quadratic equation is also positive.  Now how to get value of $a$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.Please go through this:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Put the discriminant of this quadratic less than o  .You will get the value of a

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=x^2+x+a$ then:

$$0<tan^{-1}{u}<{\pi\over 2}\to 0<tan(tan^{-1}{u})<\infty\to 0<x^2+x+a<\infty$$

$x^2+x+a$ is always non negative only if $1-4a\le0$ which concludes:

$$a\ge {1\over 4}$$

Answer (score 1):

The function $g(x)=x^2+x+a$ has a minimum at $-1/2$ and
$$
g(-1/2)=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}+a=\frac{4a-1}{4}
$$
Since both limits at $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are $\infty$, we conclude that $g(x)$ assumes all values greater than or equal to $(4a-1)/4$. Hence the image of
$$
f(x)=\arctan(x^2+x+a)
$$
is the interval
$$
[\arctan((4a-1)/4),\pi/2)
$$
so there is no way the image is $(0,\pi/2)$. The image is $[0,\pi/2)$ when $a=1/4$.